# How can I force a specific package version using go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

In my `go.mod`, I have:

```
...
require (
  ...
  sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.2.0-alpha.0
)
```

and for some reason, when I save my files, my `go.sum` gets updated to include:

```
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.2.0-alpha.0 h1:WM6lus3SNU4SsMlDYvjJ5fyLsG9nW3ffb/4/FpE2ZGrtnc=
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.2.0-alpha.0/go.mod h1:HFAsYoOh6XMV+jKF1rsUjFwrknPbowfyHEHH5fRdJMf2jMX8=
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.6.3 h1:SBbr+inLPEKhrf87vlJtrvDcwIpm+uhDvp63Bl72xYJtoOE=
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime v0.6.3/go.mod h1:WlZNXcMs40++oyaQt4B7Cs2lEE5JYRs8vJUznj4aRP4N4JpdAY=
```

The first 2, I understand why they are there. However, why does the latest version (`0.6.3`) of the package also appear all of a sudden?

When I run, `go mod tidy`, I get errors suggesting that 2 files in my codebase point to packages in the latest version (`0.6.3`) of this package. What can I do to strictly use the `0.2.2` version in go modules + in my codebase?

`go mod tidy`:

```
<filename here> imports
    sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission/builder: module sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@latest found (v0.6.3), but does not contain package sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission/builder
```

Comment: If a dependency requires 0.6.3, you will need at least that version.

Comment: @JimB that makes sense, however, my codebase worked with an even earlier version (`0.1.0`) and it builds the binary and works as expected so I'm not sure where exactly `go mod tidy` thinks I have a dependancy since when I run `git diff`, I can see that no package imports got changed in those specific files it complains about. Weird, right?

Comment: You can check `go mod graph` to see the full dependency tree, which should tell you why this version is included.

Comment: I ran `go mod graph | grep "controller-runtime"`. All I got was `v0.2.0-alpha.0`, the expected version and no mention of the "latest version" `v0.6.3`. Is that expected?

Comment: "What can I do to strictly use the 0.2.2 version in go modules + in my codebase?" Not much. What's the reason to not  use 0.6.3?

Comment: @carrots  if the version is not being used do not worry about go.sum; go.sum is just to keep track of hash for version;

Comment: What might have happened is you initially imported latest version then moved to an older version in which case it is expected that both version will be included in go.sum

Comment: Would `go mod why` help? (https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Preliminary_module_support)

Answer (score 0):

`v0.2.0-alpha.0` appears to already be the version that your module is using, so you don't need to do anything to “force” it. (The version of the `go` command that you are using may be erroneously saving the `go.sum` file before it errors out. If that reproduces with the latest version — currently `go1.16rc1` — please file an issue, with steps to reproduce it, at [https://golang.org/issue/new .](https://golang.org/issue/new%E2%80%8A.))

The error message is telling you that the `go` command is looking for a missing package (`sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission/builder`).

It is checking in the latest version of the modules that may contain that package, but the latest version (which is `v0.6.3`, whereas your module requires `v0.2.0-alpha.0`) still does not contain that package.

So the `go` command is telling you, essentially: “I am missing the package `sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/webhook/admission/builder`, and I cannot fix it by upgrading because `v0.6.3` does not contain that package either”.